# Power Management and problem resuming from Sleep/Suspend

Tags: xubuntu, suspend, power-management

I have recently made the switch from Windows 7 to Xubuntu. Things have been going relatively well. Though my main problem with the install of the new OS is how it behaves when my laptop is left idle for any amount of time.

The machine goes into a "sleep mode" (I am not sure if this is the correct terminology for Linux). But what happens is that the screen becomes blank and regardless of whether I move my mouse or press some keys on the keyboard it stays that way. I have to hold the power button on my laptop to do a hard reboot.

I have a few issues that are all regarding power modes and settings. For instance, using the 'Power Manager' application, I have set my system power saving mode to "Never" for when asked when the laptop should go into Sleep/Suspend mode. This setting seems to be completely ignored. And the system goes into a sleep mode after around 5 minutes.

This is very frustrating, as I keep losing work.

I am using an older Acer laptop (around 17 years old), it has 3GB RAM and an `Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T6400 @ 2.00GHz`

Here are the results of entering `$cat /etc/os-release`  on the Terminal

```shell
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS" NAME="Ubuntu" VERSION_ID="22.04" 
VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)" VERSION_CODENAME=jammy ID=ubuntu ID_LIKE=debian HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/" 
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/" 
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/" 
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

I can send more hardware details if necessary, the output of the commands I have tried is quite long, and I'm not sure how necessary the info is.

If anyone has any advice, or can help me with resolving this issue I would be massively appreciative. Thanks for reading.